# Django - Model field property

Tags: django

i want to calculate multiplication of `amount` and `percent` field:

```
class Info_data(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=0)
    percent = models.ForeignKey(Owner, related_name="percentage")
```

then write this property:

```
def _get_total(self):
    return self.percent * self.amount
total = property(_get_total)
```

and use in template:

```
{% for list_calculated in list_calculateds %}
<ul>
    <li>{{list_calculated.name}}</li>
    <li>{{list_calculated.total}}</li>
</ul>
{% endfor %}
```

but return blank. how to use property in template?

Comment: You can't multiply a Decimal object (your amount field) with an Owner object (your percent field) - there's an error there but the template language is hiding it. Fix the logic and it will work.

Comment: oww. yes, tanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial attempt isn't working because you are ignoring the [signature](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) of the `property`-function.

And then your solution could be improved with the help of the [property-decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17330273/630877):

```
@property
def total(self):
    return self.percent.percent * self.amount
```

Answer (score 1):

my problem solved by some property edit:

```
def _get_total(self):
        # return float(self.percent.percent) * float(self.amount)
        return float(self.percent.percent) * float(self.amount)
    total = property(_get_total)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a better solution could be to convert both to decimal (as one is already a Decimal) to avoid float point calculation errors. Pass the percent as a string for the same reason. Therefore this would become:

```
return Decimal(f'self.percent.percent') * self.amount
```